# Como fazer um um editor de texto em uma textarea no estilo TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea, tinymce

Gostaria de saber o que devo estudar exatamente para conseguir transformar uma *textarea* em um editor de texto *WYSIWYG*.Logicamente sei que devo usar *Javascript*,mas não consigo imaginar como os estilos são aplicados em tempo real no conteúdo dentro da textarea. Já pesquisei na internet e as pessoas só davam link de editores prontos. Não quero o link de um pronto. Eu gostaria de saber o caminho mais ou menos para conseguir aplicar o estilo na parte escolhida do conteúdo dentro da *textarea*. Cheguei a ver pessoas falando para usar *iframe*, mas não explicaram o que exatamente eu faria com o *iframe* pra conseguir isso.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O segredo dos editores WYSIWYG é o atributo [`contenteditable`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp). Com este atributo é possível que um elemento HTML como `<div>` ou `<p>` se torne um "input", porém mantendo a capacidade de interpretação de HTML.

Para pegar o texto atualmente selecionado e aplicar estilos no mesmo usa-se JavaScript, como você sugeriu. Porém, as APIs suportadas pelos navegadores são bastante variadas, então é necessário fazer vários tratamentos no código para oferecer suporte à vários navegadores. Por exemplo as APIs [`Window.getSelection()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) e [`Selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection).

Se você deseja estudar como os editores WYSIWYG funcionam, sugiro analisar o código-fonte dos mesmos, há muito o que ser aprendido ali. Por exemplo, [aqui](https://github.com/dineiar/jQuery-TE/blob/master/jQuery-TE_v.1.4.1/uncompressed/jquery-te-1.4.1.js) você pode encontrar o código completo do editor [jQuery-TE](https://github.com/dineiar/jQuery-TE).

Comment: Perfeito!! Exatamente o tipo de resposta que eu precisava. Muito Obrigado!!

Comment: +1 pelo atributo `contenteditable`. Aprendi uma hoje - o que mais me impressionou é que ele aparentemente é suportado há um bom tempo...